# CSS styling problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm a beginner and I have been battling to get this site to work as desired. Thanks to advice on this forum to include an IE7 specific style sheet I am almost there, but with a couple of minor issues remaining. Some of the styles just won't work and I'm starting to despair! I have three issues and if anyone can shed some light on these I'd be super happy!

1. Across all browsers (both stylesheets), 'main p' text padding on the right is only appearing on pages 'studios.htm' and 'contactus.htm' - I have no idea why and have tried playing around with all the styles without success.
2. On the 'location.htm' page I am unable to position the footer "behind" the Google Map, like the picture rows are positioned on the other pages. I have tried changing margins, padding and z-index, but nothing seems to change it - I can manage to position the *footer* in the right place but the Google Map stays "behind" it so that the bottom part of it can't be seen.
3. On IE7 ONLY: CSS text formatting doesn't seem to change the font size at all. As a result the text is too large and on pages 'studios' and 'thingstodo', this results in the very bottom part of the text to go down too low and hide behind images. If the text was the right

The site is here: http://bit.ly/gaAthc

Main CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ykbhd/
IE7 specific CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/bdwrY/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IE is... Or are you referring to lack of version information? I can't see any vanilla "IE" references in the text above.

Comment: The main CSS and IE7 CSS look alike. Shouldn't the IE7 CSS contain only the IE7 hacks?

Answer (score 2):

1) The reason this appears correct sometimes is simply how the text breaks in your paragraphs. Your `p` tags are taking the full width of your `main` div, so putting right padding isn't doing to help. Instead, just put some padding on your image.

Line 190:

```
#target2
{
    float: right;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

2) You can use negative margins the same way you do for the picture rows.

Line 178:

```
#googlemap
{
    margin-bottom: -130px;
}
```

3) Remove `margin-bottom: -10px;` from this rule:

```
#container #main #rotxt
{
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

**Update**

For the Google map footer issue in IE7, try adding this rule to a IE7 stylesheet (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for info on conditional comments):

```
#footer
{
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @wsanville - you have helped me sort out ALMOST everything! The one problem that remains is that in Internet Explorer 7 the Google Map still 'hides' behind the footer so that the very bottom part of the map cannot be seen. So, they are both positioned in the right place but the footer is 'on top' of the Google Map and I'm trying to get it the other way round... Any ideas how I can achieve this? Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help, I've updated my answer for that issue. Be sure to show some love with upvotes and accepted answers ;)

Comment: many thanks again, I tried what you suggested and included those values on the footer however now the whole Google Map 'jumped down', leaving a massive gap between itself and the content above it, and the bottom part of the Google map is still hiding behind the footer in IE7 (here is the page http://bit.ly/fxggEu). If you happen to have any other suggestions I would really appreciate them! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add overflow: hidden; to #main p